# How to create a vertical (rotated) button in Qt with C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, button, qpushbutton

I'd like to create a vertical button in Qt (using C++, not Python), with text rotated 90º either clockwise or counterclockwise. It doesn't seem to be possible with a standard QPushButton.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to create a vertical button in Qt, you can subclass `QPushButton` so that the dimensions reported by the widget are transposed, and also modify the drawing event to paint the button with the proper alignment.

Here's a class called `OrientablePushButton` that can be used as a drop-in replacement of the traditional `QPushButton` but also supports vertical orientation through the usage of `setOrientation`.

**Aspect**:

[image: Vertical button]

**Sample usage**:

```
auto anotherButton = new OrientablePushButton("Hello world world world world", this);
anotherButton->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);
anotherButton->setOrientation(OrientablePushButton::VerticalTopToBottom);
```

**Header file**:

```
class OrientablePushButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum Orientation {
        Horizontal,
        VerticalTopToBottom,
        VerticalBottomToTop
    };

    OrientablePushButton(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
    OrientablePushButton(const QString & text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    OrientablePushButton(const QIcon & icon, const QString & text, QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    QSize sizeHint() const;

    OrientablePushButton::Orientation orientation() const;
    void setOrientation(const OrientablePushButton::Orientation &orientation);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    Orientation mOrientation = Horizontal;
};
```

**Source file**:

```
#include <QPainter>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStylePainter>

OrientablePushButton::OrientablePushButton(QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(parent)
{ }

OrientablePushButton::OrientablePushButton(const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(text, parent)
{ }

OrientablePushButton::OrientablePushButton(const QIcon &icon, const QString &text, QWidget *parent)
    : QPushButton(icon, text, parent)
{ }

QSize OrientablePushButton::sizeHint() const
{
    QSize sh = QPushButton::sizeHint();

    if (mOrientation != OrientablePushButton::Horizontal)
    {
        sh.transpose();
    }

    return sh;
}

void OrientablePushButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    QStylePainter painter(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    initStyleOption(&option);

    if (mOrientation == OrientablePushButton::VerticalTopToBottom)
    {
        painter.rotate(90);
        painter.translate(0, -1 * width());
        option.rect = option.rect.transposed();
    }

    else if (mOrientation == OrientablePushButton::VerticalBottomToTop)
    {
        painter.rotate(-90);
        painter.translate(-1 * height(), 0);
        option.rect = option.rect.transposed();
    }

    painter.drawControl(QStyle::CE_PushButton, option);
}

OrientablePushButton::Orientation OrientablePushButton::orientation() const
{
    return mOrientation;
}

void OrientablePushButton::setOrientation(const OrientablePushButton::Orientation &orientation)
{
    mOrientation = orientation;
}
```